# Как на локальном сервере Apache создать хост видимый в глобальной сети Интернет?

Tags: apache, php

Как на локальном сервере Apache создать хост видимый в глобальной сети Интернет?

Comment: надо что бы был выделенный ip у тебя

Comment: Как это сделать?

Comment: у провайдера заказать

Comment: Не забудь порты открыть.

Comment: Что такое «**локальный** сервер»? Думаю, телепатов тут немного. Если ещё актуально, опишите условия подключения к Интернету как следует.

Comment: @Incnis Mrsi,  после того как я задал вопрос, прошло почти три года. За это время можно было и телепатом стать.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Listen {внешний ip}:{порт}
NameVirtualHost {внешний ip}:{порт}
```

Прописать это в конфиге хоста. Внешний ip совершенно не нужен. Достаточно не перезагружаться и не переподключаться достаточно долго.

Comment: Слышал, что если поверх IPv4 пусть IPv6, то комп будет доступен по IPv6 даже без внешнего IP)